# Creating a function to be used in multiple pages

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Basically, I am trying to create a function that will be called each time a button is clicked. I am developing a questionnaire application with 20 questions, each question has 4 possible answers. I want to create a function that takes the value of the answer when the button is clicked and stores it, this function will be basically the same for each of the 20 pages. I tried creating a function.ts file with an exported Function class but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: May I ask you to also jot down snippet from your function.

Comment: I am just using a test function now that just logs to console

export class Functions{

 function barrierClick()
{
 console.log('123');
}
}

Comment: Please [edit] your post and create a [mcve] (HTML+JS + Any other relevant parts) - You can't expect us to guess what's wrong without it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Provider/Service for this.

But if you just want to use a simple function in different components, you could try this:

functions.ts

```
export function myFunction(input) {
    // do something magic
};
```

Then import myFunction in your components

```
import { myFunction } from './functions';

// use it anywhere
myFunction(data);
```